# How can I quickly insert picture in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm making a responsive website. I smashed on top of the background image and the background that I'm adding backgrounds and text but I need to add small pictures I couldn't find how to ?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: `<img src="..">`...?!

Comment: width/height? via css.

Comment: I mean that i have a background image and i want to put a text on it.

Comment: `style="background: url(..)"`...?!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of room for interpretation here.

If you want to have multiple background-images you can do that with "CSS3".

```
background-image: url(front.png), url(back.png);
```

*Text in the element is on top of the background images.*

If you have an Image in the markup as an img-element.
You have to position your text above the image to get the same effect.
For example:

```
<div class="container">
 <img src="bg-image.png">
 <span class="text">Foreground-Text</span>
</div>

.container {position: relative;}
.text {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1;}
```

This way, the text is absolutly positioned above the image.